# Missing Controller Error in Cakephp 2.0.4

Tags: cakephp

Apologies if I ask a silly question, I am quite new to CakePhp

I have installed Cakephp 2.0.4 on dev.ayumma.com  (Used Git Clone on, Amazon ec2 machine, amazon linux, with mysql php5, etc.)

I have configured apache with mod_rewrite loaded (you can verify [here](http://dev.ayumma.com/default.php)).  I am using the cake 2.0 documentation for a development installation.

My paths are absolute you can see that [here](http://dev.ayumma.com/3/post) as I print them on the page.

I am copying code from the cakephp 2.0 [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html).

Code is in the correct folders, case is correct on file names, and I even copied and renamed files according to error message, just in case.  Database was created from the code on the tutorial.  The routes.php file has required `CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';`.

I have ruled out file location. Files are in the correct folders

I have ruled out mod_rewrite.  Seems to be loaded, not sure how else to test.

I have ruled out absolute paths.  The paths show up correctly.

I have ruled out the routes.php file. Last line is correct.

What am I missing?  Any help would be appreciated.  I am sure its probably something simple, but at this moment it is out of my grasp.

Offending page is [here](http://dev.ayumma.com/3/post).

Answer (score 1):

The erorr message means that you have not created the required controller for the posts table.

Make sure you have created Controller, Model and Views for posts table. controller file should be named as `PostsController.php`, model file as `Post.php` and View files are named as `index.ctp, view.ctp etc` .

Comment: Thank you for the feeback.  I have a Post.php, in app/model, and I have a PostController in app/Controller.  The cases match, and the files are present.  Yet I still have the issue.

Comment: according to the tutorial, controller should be plural. i.e PostsController.php and use this url http://dev.ayumma.com/3/posts

Comment: Thank you so much,  i was able to figure it out.